# Quickly delete 1000s of members

Tags: members

I've picked up an old EE 1.6 site that has 58k spam member accounts. Anybody got a safe way to delete them all without going through every paginated screen in the CMS? It's on a live server but I suppose I could edit the SQL to change pagination.

I'd rather do it directly in myqsql though I think, but I want to make sure no table relationships are broken.

Comment: Are you deleting all the members or just specific ones?

Comment: Indeed - is there a specific criteria you are using to determine who is a spam account and who is not?

Comment: I just had to do this the other day. Can't remember the exact queries I used, but here is what I did:

1. delete all members in the Pending member group
2. delete all members whose last_visit date wasn't set
3. Find common spammy email domains and then delete from exp_members, exp_member_homepage, exp_member_data where the email address contains that spammy domain.

But, I didn't know about the member account pruning, so you may want to start there.

Comment: Basically ALL members in the group 'Members' can be binned as we don't use that group at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the members you are deleting have something simple in common (e.g. They never logged-in
) then you can use the member clean up tools - these might work for you.

Go CP Home  ›  Admin  ›  Utilities  ›  Data Pruning  ›  Membership Account Pruning

Obviously back-up first before even looking at this and YMMV but for EE 1.6 the data pruning might be handy.

Comment: This is what I would recommend.

Comment: Good shout. I'll give that a go and update the question with the result

Comment: It works. Sadly the script times out a lot but if you do it in reasonably sized batches it works OK. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to delete 1000s of members is to use the following SQL after backing up your database:

```
DELETE
FROM `exp_members`
WHERE `group_id` =x
```

x is the member group number you want to delete members from.

Comment: Thanks fmz I removed about 300K users from my site with that SQL command. I backed up before tho. DB was 140MB compressed. Is now just 5mb compressed,

Answer (score -1):

I would think your best bet is backing up the DB in production, writing a script to test the removal on your local machine, performing the update on your local machine, importing the changes back to the DB.

You might have to do a site-wide content freeze for a few hours, but that's pretty standard in situations like this.